# How to re-size a multidimensional vector? C++

Tags: c++, vector

How would I re-size a multidimensional vector to x wide and y high?
If my matrix is:

```
vector<vector<float> > matrix;
```

Would this work?

```
matrix.resize(x);
for (int i; i < x; i++){
 matrix[x].resize(y);
}
```

Comment: That depends on what the undefined behaviour you invoked does.  It could do what you want under the standard, or it could format your harddrive.  Harddrive format more likely.

Comment: Yes, but when I check the size, it returns what seem to be incorrect numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matrix.resize(x); // this will resize the outer vector to be of size x
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    matrix[x].resize(y); // this will attempt to access 1 passed the size you set.
}
```

I think you meant to type `matrix[i]`.

But yes, `std::vector::resize` will resize both the outer and inner vectors as long as you make sure you loop properly.

[Example](http://ideone.com/KK85Pz)

Comment: You also need to initialize `i`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley True - good catch (though, I don't use a hand-written loop in my example).